# I can't create a workspace with 'ng new myworkspace' command in Angular7. What could be the cause

Tags: node.js, angular

When I execute this:

```
ng new myapp
```

[It generates the following error below:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpS0K.png)

[This is my Angular version and it's my first installation:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YanG.png)

I initially installed nodejs standalone but had to uninstall it when I wanted to install nvm-windows based on the installation instructions, which didn't work after so much trouble trying to get it to work. And at the end, I had to install 'nodist'. I have the feeling that the problem is from nodejs, it's not properly configured.

Please I desperately need your help, guys.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your node.js version?

Comment: Please post your text errors as text, not as pictures.

Comment: based on your description I would suggest to reinstall nodejs using installer msi . but first use something like ccleaner to clean everything related to nodejs, and the registry. https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.15.3/node-v10.15.3-x64.msi

Comment: I have versions 8.12.0, 10.15.3, and 11.11.0. I have npm versions 4.0.5,.4.5.0, and 6.1.0. Thanks.

Comment: @Exlord, I have done as you have said. I have reinstalled node but when I run: 
`node -v`

Answer (score 0):

remove node module and Uninstall the node

reinstall the application angular.io with globally

npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: I used 'npm install -g @angular/cli' command to install Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Try theses two options if you didn't :
- Run the `ng new myapp` in cmd.exe (not Git Bash)
- Try a fresh install of Node, Npm and @angular/cli

I hope it will help !

Comment: I have uninstalled nodist and installed standalone node, but when I run: 
`node -v`

I get this:
`v10.15.3`

And with this:
`npm -v`

I get this:
`'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules
\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external com
mand,
operable program or batch file.
6.4.1`

This is not normal I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the help. I really appreciate it. I have been able to solve the problem. The problem was with the `ComSpec` in the PATH variable. It had more than one value. It was supposed to have one and a specific value, i.e, `C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe` at all times. After setting it to a single value, I ran `npm -v` in my command line, another error showed up, and I then closed and ran `npm -v`command on my cmd as Admin and the problem was solved.

So, if anyone is installing nodejs on windows and encounters this kind of error:

```
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules \npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external com mand, operable program or batch file. 6.4.1
```

the tweak up there could be the solution.